# Does the UA revised ranger's companion keep its skill bonuses?

Tags: dnd-5e, ranger, animal-companions, optional-rules

In the September 2016 Unearthed Arcana [*The Ranger, Revised*](http://dnd.wizards.com/articles/features/unearthed-arcana-ranger-revised), it says:

> Your companion uses your proficiency bonus rather than its own.

The ape, for example, has a +5 bonus to Athletics and +3 to Perception. When the ape becomes a ranger's companion, does the ranger's proficiency bonus compound with these bonuses or replace them? That is, are these bonuses considered the ape's "proficiency bonus"?

It also says:

> Your animal companion gains proficiency in two skills of your choice.

Is the ape considered already proficient with Athletics and Perception?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The Ape is proficient with both of those skills. From the [D&D5e SRD](http://media.wizards.com/2016/downloads/DND/SRD-OGL_V5.1.pdf):

> The    Skills  entry   is  reserved    for monsters    that    are 
>   proficient  in  one or  more    skills.

That same document has a Proficiency Bonus by Challenge Rating table that says that a CR 1/2 creature, like the Ape, has a proficiency bonus of +2. We can then take the stat bonuses from the 16 Str (+3) and 12 Wis (+1) to get the Ape's total modifiers to those skills.

So to determine what the Ape Companion's actual modifiers are for those skills you would take the stat bonus (+3 and +1) and add the ranger's proficiency bonus. You would do the same thing for the other skills you choose for it to learn.