# Revised Ranger, Beast Conclave - Blood Hawk

Tags: dnd-5e, ranger, unearthed-arcana

Ok, I'm dumb, I've read like dozens of topics and I still don't get it.

*Your animal companion has abilities and game statistics determined in part by your level. Your companion uses **your proficiency bonus** rather than its own. In addition to the areas where it normally uses its proficiency bonus, an animal companion also **adds its proficiency bonus to its AC and to its damage rolls**.
Your animal companion gains proficiency in two skills of your choice. It also becomes proficient with all saving throws.*

Let's say I have Blood Hawk pet:

> - Armor Class: 12 **+2 From MY PROF?** = 14
> - Hit Points : 7(2d6)
> - STR 6(-2) DEX 14(+2) CON 10(0) INT 3(-4) WIS 14(+2) CHA 5(-3)
> - Proficiency Bonus +2 - **the same as my PC**
> - Skills: Perception +4 - **what about this? is it just +2 wis and +2 prof bonus?**
> - Senses: passive Perception 14 - **is this 10 + Wis Mod +2 and Perception Prof +2?**
> - Keen Sight.The hawk has advantage on Wisdom (Perception) checks that rely on sight. - **so if PP is 14, PP that rely on sight is 19? *OR* it's 10+2(wis)+2(prof)+4(hawk skill)=18 + 5 adv =23? that's kinda... broken?**
> - Pack Tactics. The hawk has advantage on an attack roll against a creature if at least one of the hawk's allies is within 5 feet of the creature and the ally isn't incapacitated.
> - Actions: Beak. Melee Weapon Attack: +4 to hit, reach 5 ft., one target. Hit: 4 (1d4 + 2 **+2**) piercing damage. - **that +2 because of PC prof?**

- *Your animal companion gains proficiency in two skills of your choice.* **so TWO extra beside Perception?**
- *You have an innate ability to communicate with beasts, and they recognize you as a kindred spirit. Through sounds and gestures, you can communicate simple ideas to a beast as an action, and can read its basic mood and intent.* - **So if I would send that Hawk for a recon it could "tell" me if there are enemies or traps?**

Comment: Related answer for this [here it is](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/94304/22566)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is [a related question and answer here](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/94304/22566) with more detailed explanation, but to answer your specific questions in order:

> • Skills: Perception +4 - what about this? is it just +2 wis and +2 prof bonus?

Yes.

> • Senses: passive Perception 14 - is this 10 + Wis Mod +2 and Perception Prof +2?

Yes.

> • Keen Sight. The hawk has advantage on Wisdom (Perception) checks that rely on sight. - so if PP is 14, PP that rely on sight is 19?

Yes.  It would need to have expertise to have proficiency bonuses added again.

> • Actions: Beak. Melee Weapon Attack: +4 to hit, reach 5 ft., one target. Hit: 4 (1d4 + 2 +2) piercing damage. - that +2 because of PC prof?

Yes.

> Your animal companion gains proficiency in two skills of your choice. So TWO extra beside Perception?

Yes, you pick them.  (One of the nicer features of this particular UA).

> So if I would send that Hawk for a recon it could "tell" me if there are enemies or traps?

Yes, but not telepathically the way a familiar does. It would need to get back into communication range with you.